# Highlighting indented menus using list items in vertical navbar

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I created a fixed, vertical navbar on the left of my site that includes several sub pages, indented in the menu. I'm just using a basic unordered list for the menus. I'd like both the Active and Hover highlight colors to go across the full width of the navbar. But the way I've got it setup right now, the indented sub menus Active and Hover colors are only as wide as the List Items that contain them. Is there a way to force the highlight colors of the indented sub menus to be the full width of the navbar?

```css
ul {
  margin-left: 46px;
}

li {
  color: #3BCBF6;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* margin-left: 46px; indenets the 'MIP Data Sets' menu */

ul#navmenu {
  background-color: #00101E;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  /* removes bullets */
}

ul#navmenu li {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0px;
  color: #3BCBF6;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul#navmenu li a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  color: #3BCBF6;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#navmenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #083B4A;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 25px;
}


/* up state menu text color in ul#navmenu li a:  #3BCBF6 (aqua) */

body#page1 li#link1 a,
body#page2 li#link2 a,
body#page3 li#link3 a,
body#page4 li#link4 a,
body#page5 li#link5 a,
body#page6 li#link6 a,
body#page7 li#link7 a,
body#page8 li#link8 a {
  background-color: #3140b2;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  max-width: 1500px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul id="navmenu">
    <li id="link1"><a href="page1.html">Home</a></li>
    <li id="link2"><a href="page2.html">Data Service Catalog</a></li>
    <li id="link3"><a href="page3.html">Platforms</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li>MIP Data Sets</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li id="link4"><a href="page4.html">M2 Data</a></li>
      <li id="link5"><a href="page5.html">MDR Data</a></li>
      <li id="link6"><a href="page6.html">COHORT Data</a></li>
      <li id="link7"><a href="page7.html">HSDW Data</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li id="link8"><a href="page8.html">CarePoint</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: sorry; had to figure out how to add my css without getting that 'your code isn't code' error message :-)

Comment: I've included on your code in the snippet. Click "Run code snippet" to see it working (refresh the page if you don't see the button).

Comment: Protip: when you find yourself putting stacks of IDs in your CSS you've gone off the road. Use a class or a descendant selector: `#navmenu li a` or simply `.my-nav-anchor-class`.  Ideally, you don't have _any_ IDs in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the height of each item (`30px`), you can add an absolutely positioned pseudo-element (`::before`) with the background.

Changes:
* The pseudo-element positioning context would be the `ul#navmenu`, so we can stretch it from side to side. Add `position: relative` to the `#navmenu`.

- The hover rule to effect the list item, and not the `a`:
  `ul#navmenu li:hover`, `ul#navmenu li:hover::before` & `ul#navmenu li:hover a`
- The `a` element should always on top of the pseudo-element (`position: relative`, `z-index: 0`), and it's `color` should be `white` on hover.
- The pseudo-element (`::before`) should have `left` and `right` values of `0`, so it will stretch from side to side, and a fixed height of `30px` like the `a` (you might want to extract that to a CSS variable).

See comments in style:

```css
ul {
  margin-left: 46px;
  list-style: inside;
}

li {
  color: #3BCBF6;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

ul#navmenu {
  position: relative; /** this makes it the posioning context for the pseudo-element **/
  
  background-color: #00101E;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul#navmenu li {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0px;
  color: #3BCBF6;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul#navmenu li a {
  /** position the link above the pseudo-element **/
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
    
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  color: #3BCBF6;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#navmenu li:hover {
  padding-left: 25px;
  /** all other styles are moved to the a or the ::before **/
}

/** the background pseudo-element **/
ul#navmenu li:hover::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #083B4A;
  height: 30px;
  content: '';
}

ul#navmenu li:hover a {
  color: white; /** color the link **/
}

body#page1 li#link1 a,
body#page2 li#link2 a,
body#page3 li#link3 a,
body#page4 li#link4 a,
body#page5 li#link5 a,
body#page6 li#link6 a,
body#page7 li#link7 a,
body#page8 li#link8 a {
  background-color: #3140b2;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  max-width: 1500px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul id="navmenu">
    <li id="link1"><a href="page1.html">Home</a></li>
    <li id="link2"><a href="page2.html">Data Service Catalog</a></li>
    <li id="link3"><a href="page3.html">Platforms</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li>MIP Data Sets</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li id="link4"><a href="page4.html">M2 Data</a></li>
      <li id="link5"><a href="page5.html">MDR Data</a></li>
      <li id="link6"><a href="page6.html">COHORT Data</a></li>
      <li id="link7"><a href="page7.html">HSDW Data</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li id="link8"><a href="page8.html">CarePoint</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahhh.. Pseudo-element positioning is new to me. Your solution looks very promising. I really appreciate your pro tip re: putting stacks of IDs in CSS Ori! I'm a Designer who's been asked by the boss to see if I can create the site without a Developer at my disposal. Been a bit of a challenge. Thank you for your expertise and assistance. Stackoverflow is truly awesome!

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't want to confuse you, but you should refrain from using ids and tag names for styling (use classes instead), and you don't need to add the id/class to the tag name - `ul#navmenu` is too specific. You can use just `#navmenu` or better yet `. navmenu`. Ids should be used for event handling mainly.

Comment: I had to set the padding of the ul#navmenu li:hover to 0 ...so the text is in the same place hovering/active. Seems to me Un-ordered Lists cause a lot of headaches when used for nav menus. Ori, is there a way to reduce the width of the lavendar 'background-color: #3140b2' ... so it doesn't hang over on the right side of the sidebar for the 4 sub menus (M2, MDR, COHORT, HSDW)?

Comment: Run the snippet in my answer bu clicking "Run code snippet". It doesn't hangs out of the right side because I've added `right: 0`. I though that the moving text was part of the original design. If it's not - remove the `li:hover` rule with the padding.

Comment: to clarify; the each menu turns lavendar once clicked, to show it's the active page. I'm guessing you can't replicate that because the other pages aren't included in the snippet.

Comment: Use the same styled of `:hover` for the active state (`.active` class for example).

Comment: I'm sorry to be so obtuse, but I don't have an 'active state' in the html or css. The only place the lavendar color is referenced is in: body#page1 li#link1 a, body#page2 li#link2 a, body#page3 li#link3 a, body#page4 li#link4 a, body#page5 li#link5 a, body#page6 li#link6 a, body#page7 li#link7 a, body#page8 li#link8 a {background-color: #3140b2; color: white; padding-left: 25px; max-width: 276px;

Comment: All I'm going for here is this kind of treatment: https://designsystem.digital.gov/components/sidenav/